# Untrusted connection!

Tags: bug

I tried to open this [link](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/672/guidelines-for-critique-questions) , but it shows **" This Connection is Untrusted "**. Is this normal and even I don't want(fear) to open this link and never had this before.

> [image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stack Exchange's HTTPS support is currently in an "alpha" state: it *more or less* works, but not all the quirks have been ironed out.

One of the quirks is that the [wildcard SSL certificate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_certificate) used by SE does not match the meta sites.  This turns out to be caused by technical / historical limitations — you simply can't have a wildcard cert for a pattern like "`meta.*.stackexchange.com`", at least not one that most browsers would accept.  Given the number of sites Stack Exchange has, the alternative of listing each site meta as a separate "alternative name" on the certificate isn't practical either.

The current plan seems to be to, eventually, switch the hostnames for the per-site metas from "`meta.sitename.stackexchange.com`" to "`sitename.meta.stackexchange.com`", which will allow a single wildcard certificate for "`*.meta.stackexchange.com`" to match them all.  In the mean time, however, those of us who want to browse Stack Exchange over HTTPS will just have to live with scary certificate warnings on the meta sites.

Ps. Nick Craver has [a nice writeup of these issues](http://nickcraver.com/blog/2013/04/23/stackoverflow-com-the-road-to-ssl/) on his blog, which is where I got most of this information from.

Comment: thanks for the info!!!!!!