# Popular questions about Graphic Design - Start Here

Tags: discussion

I often find it hard to find back the old answers that fit the most popular "duplicate".

What do you think of creating a Meta that would be updated (when needed) and would contain all the links to the most popular questions/answers we use as duplicate?

This could be a featured Meta so we could all have a quick access to it. That would make it easier to close-as-duplicate sometimes.

I'd make it simple and as a list. There could be more than one answer for each question.

---

**Resolution for large formats printing:**

[What resolution should a large format artwork for print be?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/487/what-resolution-should-a-large-format-artwork-for-print-be)

---

**How to formulate critique question (e.g. Need feedback on a design project? Read this!)**

[Guidelines for critique questions](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/672/guidelines-for-critique-questions)

---

**How to convert a Pantone to CMYK:**

[What is the difference between CMYK and RGB? Are there other color spaces I should know?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/60/what-is-the-difference-between-cmyk-and-rgb-are-there-other-color-spaces-i-shou)

[Pantone color conversions](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/25266/pantone-color-conversions)

[Mismatched CMYK Values](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/34993/mismatched-cmyk-values)

[How do Pantone coated and uncoated colors relate?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/36137/how-do-pantone-coated-and-uncoated-colors-relate)

---

**What is bleed?**

[What is page bleed and how can I avoid issues with it ?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/129/what-is-page-bleed-and-how-can-i-avoid-issues-with-it)

[How can I determine how much bleed to use?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/55905/how-can-i-determine-how-much-bleed-to-use)

---

**How to prepare my files print-ready?**

[How to prepare a design for CMYK printing?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/16512/how-to-prepare-a-design-for-cmyk-printing)

[crop marks for print in photoshop](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/65663/crop-marks-for-print-in-photoshop)

[Which file format is best for printing?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/58921/which-file-format-is-best-for-printing)

---

**How to change resolution in Photoshop?**

[Will changing image resolution from 300 to 72 without resampling reduce the quality?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/20294/will-changing-image-resolution-from-300-to-72-without-resampling-reduce-the-qual)

---

**How to make sure my file are using Pantone Spot Colors?**

[What does it mean when printers have told me my colour is not a Pantone colour, but in my file it is?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/63135/what-does-it-mean-when-printers-have-told-me-my-colour-is-not-a-pantone-colour)

[How to find a Pantone Color in Illustrator?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/41805/how-to-find-a-pantone-color-in-illustrator?lq=1)

---

**How to convert my Pantone colors?**

[How To Convert Pantone Tint to similar Pantone Color](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/63160/how-to-convert-pantone-tint-to-similar-pantone-color)

[How to convert Pantone 7C to TPX?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/58773/how-to-convert-pantone-7c-to-tpx)

[How can one accurately reproduce color from an already printed (hard copy) color block?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/65097/how-can-one-accurately-reproduce-color-from-an-already-printed-hard-copy-color)

---

**RGB to CMYK color conversion**

[Why are my printed colors duller than expected?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/57864/why-are-my-printed-colors-duller-than-expected?lq=1)

[How do I edit my CMYK greens to output as brightly as possible?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/57910/how-do-i-edit-my-cmyk-greens-to-output-as-brightly-as-possible)

[RGB and CMYK: Why both?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/7815/rgb-and-cmyk-why-both?rq=1)

---

**Working with large files: Performance issues / slow computer**

[Working with physically large (150''+) canvas sizes](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/63298/working-with-physically-large-150-canvas-sizes)

---

**How to use the Pathfinder tool in Illustrator (or how to cut out shapes from another shape)**

[Pathfinder divide tool on object with gradient mesh](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/20182/pathfinder-divide-tool-on-object-with-gradient-mesh?rq=1)

[How to make an area transparent in Illustrator](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/38794/how-to-make-an-area-transparent-in-illustrator)

[Cut strokes from other shapes via pathfinder](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/39611/cut-strokes-from-other-shapes-via-pathfinder)

[Merging separate paths in Illustrator](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/29327/merging-separate-paths-in-illustrator?lq=1)

[How to subtract text from a shape in Adobe Illustrator?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/11338/how-to-subtract-text-from-a-shape-in-adobe-illustrator?rq=1)

[White Lines (Not Strokes) Appearing between shapes after using Pathfinder tool. How do I get rid of them?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/64885/white-lines-not-strokes-appearing-between-shapes-after-using-pathfinder-tool?rq=1)

[How do I clean up my layers after outlining strokes and dividing?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/59087/how-do-i-clean-up-my-layers-after-outlining-strokes-and-dividing?rq=1)

---

**Image dimension difference when importing from Photoshop to Illustrator, why?**

[Photoshop / Illustrator / InDesign - placed image different dimensions and resolution](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/63085/ps-id-ai-placed-image-dimensions-and-resolution)

---

Comment: you can do eet!

Comment: @Ryan Then I'll get started on this, Dear Leader! I'm hoping I'll get some help and suggestions from the other users with a big memory too, there's so many questions and good answers on this site! :)

Comment: I just added some links. Only one I couldn't find / wasn't sure what you meant is the pathfinder one. There are a bunch of questions, but none broad enough to cover "pathfinder issues".

Comment: While fishing for Qs, I also noticed some keep returning but have no real reference we can link to. In those cases, we would need to create a question and answers. For example: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/65172/is-our-company-logo-too-similar-to-this-established-brand Is it worth making another list of Qs we still need? (in this case "How do I determine if my logo is too similar to an existing one?"

Comment: While we're looking through common questions, consider this related similar idea (which didn't quite happen... hopefully this attempt will fare better): [Can we have a canonical “One beginner design question to (link to) them all”?](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/can-we-have-a-canonical-one-beginner-design-question-to-link-to-them-all)

Answer (score 9):

Here are some other possible questions based on votes. I'll keep adding more as I find them. Ideally, we should make sure the ones we use as reference Qs are cleared of long comment exchanges and *generally well-presented* :P

**Print:**

- [What kind of black should I use when designing for CMYK print?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2984/what-kind-of-black-should-i-use-when-designing-for-cmyk-print)
- [What should you ask the printer?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/21497/what-should-you-ask-the-printer)

**Font identification and pairing:**

- ***[How can I know what fonts a website is using?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/65366/how-can-i-know-what-fonts-a-website-is-using)*** (new question - created so we can link to it)
- [What are best practices for choosing and pairing fonts?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-are-best-practices-for-choosing-and-pairing-fonts) (this is good one for all those "What matches font X?"
- [How can I describe the font I am looking for or looking at?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/29280/how-can-i-describe-the-font-i-am-looking-for-or-looking-at)
- [What is the difference between a font and a typeface?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/12717/what-is-the-difference-between-a-font-and-a-typeface)

**Finding assets:**

- [Where are some good places to find royalty free stock images?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/115/where-are-some-good-places-to-find-royalty-free-stock-images) (might be getting old though)

**Design, designers and creativity:**

- [Tips and resources for beginning designers](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/31/tips-and-resources-for-beginning-designers)
- [How do I learn to be creative?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2167/how-do-i-learn-to-be-creative)
- [What is the single most influential book every designer should read?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/58/what-is-the-single-most-influential-book-every-designer-should-read)
- [How do you break out of current creative mind sets?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/13178/how-do-you-break-out-of-current-creative-mind-sets)
- [What technical/objective qualities do good logos have?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/27/what-technical-objective-qualities-do-good-logos-have) (good for "Is my logo good?" when there is no elaboration to make it into a critique Q)
- [What price should I charge for design services?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/957/what-price-should-i-charge-for-design-services)
- [How can I improve my color selection skill?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/3245/how-can-i-improve-my-color-selection-skill) and [Methods for improving color choice and combinations?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/50742/methods-for-improving-color-choice-and-combinations)
- [How does one generate a palette similar to the ones in Google's material design?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/37520/how-does-one-generate-a-palette-similar-to-the-ones-in-googles-material-design)

**Software:**

- [Making the background of an image transparent in Gimp](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/5446/making-the-background-of-an-image-transparent-in-gimp) (this used to show up a lot, not sure now)
- [Professionals: Would you choose GIMP over Photoshop and/or Inkscape over Illustrator?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/825/professionals-would-you-choose-gimp-over-photoshop-and-or-inkscape-over-illustr)
- [How to get dashed line in Photoshop?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/235/how-to-get-dashed-line-in-photoshop)
- [How to change the color of the artboard in Adobe Illustrator?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/31053/how-to-change-the-color-of-the-artboard-in-adobe-illustrator)
- [How do I combine two objects into one in Illustrator?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/999/how-do-i-combine-two-objects-into-one-in-illustrator)

**Image Quality:**

- [How can I increase the size of a .jpeg without losing quality?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/21568/how-can-i-increase-the-size-of-a-jpeg-without-losing-quality) (I constantly see questions that ask about increasing an image's size without losing quality, please add others/betters ones if you come across them)