# Are design critiques acceptable on here?

Tags: discussion, critique

I know this question kind of defeats the purpose of me asking, but is it acceptable to post projects on here to be critiqued? If not I'll take this down ASAP.

Comment: I'm going to go out on limb and say no. This is more of a "I have a problem and what I tried isn't working. Any suggestions?" type board.

Comment: @ErickP no its not, but that is the easiest question to ask so its what one usually gets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes they are allowed. However, we do have Critique Guidelines so that they are narrow and focused questions. What is not permitted is a broad question like, "How can I make this better?" Please review our Critique Guidelines available:

[Guidelines for critique questions](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/672/guidelines-for-critique-questions)

Comment: Wow, I've been on this site for a few days now and didn't even see the meta section... Thanks! @ryan

Comment: Good to know. I stand corrected. ;)